# How can I make this thread stop

Tags: java, multithreading

So that is my question how can I make the thread stop, I am not very proficient in threads but the little information I have read tell me that this should work.

```
public class testestes {
    static volatile boolean key;

    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        key=true;
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(key)
                {
                    System.out.println("running");
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        key=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it DOES stop.

Comment: I don't get it either, once the call to `run()` was changed to `start()`, the new thread runs, and when key is set to false, the new **thread stops**. That code works fine for me. The problem must be in code that's not been posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **would not** use a `boolean` to check whether the thread should **terminate**. If you use `volatile` as a field modifier, this will work reliable, but if your code becomes more complex, for instead uses other blocking methods inside the `while` loop, it might happen, that your code will **not terminate** at all or at least **takes longer** as you might want.

> Certain blocking library methods support interruption.

Every thread has already a boolean flag **interrupted status** and you should make use of it. It can be implemented like this:

```
public void run() {

   try {
      while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
         // ...
      }
   } catch (InterruptedException consumed)
      /* Allow thread to exit */
   }

}

public void cancel() { interrupt(); }
```

Source code taken from [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/). Since the `cancel()` method is public you can let another thread invoke this method as you wanted.

There is also a poorly named static method `interrupted` which clears the interrupted status of the current thread.

Comment: I ended up using this solution although this is not the answer to my initial question this is the actual answer to my problem, and it seems to be the best option. (I swear that in my PC the code snippet wasn't stopping, I still don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `thread.start();`, NOT `thread.run();`. run() won't fork.

Also, it's probably going to be the case that you won't see any "running" output because you're immediately setting `key` to false after you fork so when the forked thread enters `run()`, `key` is already false.

Comment: my problem is that I cannot stop output from appearing, I want to stop the thread not make it run.

Comment: @crusader When you call `thread.start()` instead of `thread.run()` you can't stop the output from appearing?

Comment: You can call System.exit, if you want to stop the entire thing (JVM), but I'm not sure if this is the solution you want.

Comment: @Joset this is a simplification of a problem I have with an application, what I want is to stop a thread given a flag that the main thread of the program can modify, some sources online state that by using volatile in a variable it is possible to somehow make two threads communicate, at least that is what I understood, but it doesn't work.

tl;dr I want to stop a thread by changing a flag with a different thread.

Comment: The best way of stopping any thread is to not attempt it unless you are an OS terminating a whole process.

Comment: @MartinJames The OP made clear, that he/she is fully aware of the cooperative mechanism which is used in Java to tell a thread to shutdown. Hence, when talking about ***stoping a thread*** it does not have to mean you want to kill it brutally.

Answer (score 0):

The basic layout for doing this is to actually have a class that implements Runnable.

```
public class SampleThread implements Runnable
{
  private volatile boolean stopFlag = false;

  public void stopThisThread()
  {
    stopFlag = true;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    while (!stopFlag)
    {
      //doStuff
    }
  }
}
```

Then elsewhere

```
SampleThread sample = new SampleThread();
new Thread(sample).start();
//Then when you want to kill it...
sample.stopThisThread();
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique posed in your simplified code *should* work.  I can confirm at least that it works on my desktop.  Have you tested the simplified version locally?  Maybe there's something going on in your actual version that isn't being represented here, like a use of a non-static variable or an additional condition that must also be met.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to look into interrupting the thread with [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).  There's a good article about it in the Java Tutorials.

The answers suggesting a **boolean** flag are equally correct.  In either case, you're going to check in some conditional statement somewhere to see if your thread should terminate.  The condition for termination could be either that the thread was interrupted or its boolean flag was set (depending on which implementation you choose).

One final word of warning: never use Thread.stop().  It is deprecated for a good reason.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for a good explanation.